# Distributed system design using only C

Tags: c, algorithm, network-programming, distributed

I have the work of implementing a distributed system of nodes (like p2p nodes) each of these nodes (lets say A,B,C and D) perform certain functions and need to interact with each other for various operations such as synchronize operations and other things like 15 A nodes interact with a group of 5 B nodes to get into the least loaded node's queue and get a token number and thereafter wait for C to redirect them to a free node D and so on.

I am a bit lost as to how should i go about the design:

1. The protocol that i have thought of is to encapsulate a struct of the type of operation and other things to be sent. Also, this is done using an acknowledgment scheme so i can be sure the other side got the message.
2. How do i go about the distributed mutual exclusion aspect as I do not have a central server. I am guessing each node replicates the data, but this sounds a bit too expensive(not to mention stupid).
3. What is the basic design methodology followed while implementing p2p systems, ie how do i implement the program such that it is blocked on a receive but also can send further updates et al and at the same time get information from others about the 'state' of the whole system.
4. How do i ensure total ordering of requests?

Also, what are the other issues that I may need to look at/face. I also would appreciate if you could point me towards some good online resources on implementing p2p and distributed systems.

Thanks!!

Comment: you are signing up for lots of pain: why not consider Erlang for example? This would help you solve lots of the problems e.g. networking, distributed, serialization, marshaling etc.

Comment: You say "using only C" but tag the question as both "c" and "c++."  Which one is it?

Comment: and why is this community wiki? do know that this lowers your chances of getting decent answers...

Comment: didn't know that. I just thought of the wiki concept and thought people may refine my query towards something more precise than what i described. How do i remove that attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't try to give a "whole" answer (because the question is way too large & vague anyways) but I could point you towards an interesting piece of the puzzle:

1. You could use a Message Queuing system (e.g. AMQP [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/): there is an experimental C binding available) to implement reliable message delivery between your nodes.
2. Mutual Exclusion: you can use a protocol such as [Paxos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_algorithm)

Comment: I will look at paxos. The requirement is to simply build a distributed serverless system of nodes which need to collaborate to process a job in a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The secret to prevent blocking is your end points must all be written as servers with threads for "protocol" processing that are separate from the threads for data processing.

As for line protocol, I've become enamored with JSON for line protocol. It is human readable. It is streamable without need for length bytes! It is easily extensible and mostly immune to protocol version change.

Comment: Can you elaborate or give references to the **The secret to prevent blocking is your end points must all be written as servers with threads for "protocol"** part of the answer. It would be of great help. Also How do i ensure total ordering of events?

Comment: Look into the design of FTP. There is a protocol port where the client talks to the server. Only protocol data is sent over this connection. Data transfer takes place over a separate connection. This allows the server and client to react to changing conditions faster. As for total ordering of events that is impossible in a p2p design. It is also meaningless in a p2p protocol. If a sends to b and c sends to d does it matter which happens first?

Answer (score -1):

Yet another piece of software worth a look could be KadC!

http://kadc.sourceforge.net